# Does $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac13 (\frac{n+1}{n})^{n^2}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am studying the convergence of
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac13 \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2} $$

---

Let $a_n = \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$

Using the root test:

$$ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}\right) = \lim _{n\to \infty }\ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} = e \in \mathbb{R}$$

Therefore, $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac13 \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2} < + \infty $$

---

[Wolfram has another opinion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum%20_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%20%7D%20%5Cfrac13%20%28%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B1%7D%7Bn%7D%29%5E%7Bn%5E2%7D) and I'm confused.

Who is right? Me or Wolfie?

Comment: Review the conditions for root test. What does root test $= e$ tell you?

Comment: $(\frac{n+1}{n})^{n^2} \gt 1+n^2\frac 1n$ Then comparision test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root test says if $\lim a_n^{1/n} <1$ that the series is convergent. If it is $>1$ then it is divergent. In this case, the limit $e$ is greater than $1$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks Kavi

Answer (score 4):

The series diverges as its general term doesn't even converge to zero. You have

$$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2} > \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n > 1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}\right) = \lim _{n\to \infty }\ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} = e >1 $$ so from the root test series diverges.Wolfram has right opinion haha

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\implies \log(a_n)=n^2 \log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=n-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}\sim e^{n-\frac 12}$$